# Create video with an image and audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg

I want to make a simple video with a jpeg image and a mp3 audio file using ffmpeg. I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg) command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

and get this error:

```
[swscaler @ 0x555f60538b40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x555f60594d40] height not divisible by 2 (550x765)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

I can't make sense of it. Could you correct the command for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vf "scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p" -shortest -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

The scale filter example is a fancy way of making the width and height to be divisible by 2 which is needed for this particular encoder when outputting YUV 4:2:0 (4:2:2 and 4:4:4 are not supported by most players, so that is why you see so many examples using `yuv420p`).

A simpler method is to crop or scale like `crop=550:764`, but the above command will work with any input size.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That worked. What would the command look like if I watned to place two images side by side?

Comment: @H3R3T1K `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i left.jpg -loop 1 -i right.jpg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]hstack=inputs=2,scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

Comment: @IIogan [swscaler @ 0x563d38f43f00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0x563d390c9d00] Input 1 height 662 does not match input 0 height 765.
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0x563d390c9d00] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: @H3R3T1K I was assuming each input was the same height. Use the scale filter to make them the same height.

Comment: @IIogan could you post the code for it? Thanks much!

Comment: @H3R3T1K Should be asked as a new, standalone question since it's different than the one here. Make sure to show your command and the complete log.

Comment: I was able to successfully use `vf -scale=1920:-2` to scale my image for this usecase. Is there any difference between that solution and the more advanced filter you used to do the same, or is it just that it will work without me needing to know anything about the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @HashimAziz If you already know one of the dimensions you need then your solution is just fine (and is what I usually do). The solution in the answer is just a precaution so users can copy and paste the answer for any arbitrary sized input without having to know anything or deal with making the width or height divisible by 2.

Comment: Failed for me with the error: `Invalid size 'iw-mod(iw'`